# Installation of Away 3d 4.0

Tags: actionscript, flashdevelop, away3d

I have some programming experience with Actionscript 3 and am totally new to Away3d. I have not been successful in installing the library on FlashDevelop, which is my favorite editor, although I also like FDT ( free version though... ). If someone out there could patiently walk me through the installation process I would immensely appreciate the courtesy.  Marcos

Answer (score 1):

You might use [this excellent tutorial for setup your project](http://www.mclelun.com/blog/2011/03/flashdevelop-molehill-away3d/). Flash is just no more in beta stadium, so if you didn't already download it from adobe sites, do it [here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html) not from those links in the tutorial (and yeah, version number little differs).

If you'll have some specific questions (or errors) feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to install it. Away3D is a library, so just follow these steps:

1 - Download here http://away3d.com/download/ for free the sec file or the source files;

2 - if you have downloaded the swf file, just put it inside your projects path (anywhere inside), right click it and choose "add to library". You are done.

3 - if you have downloaded the source code (you can edit it as you like and better understand the process) you can just open it, enter src folder and move it's contents to your project`s src folder. You are done.